# Issue with execution order in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, execution

I'm relatively new to javascript so please hold it against me.

I have a bit of code which should give the user a little time to reach the submenu from the base-menu.
My problem is that the code keeps executing in a weird order.

Here is the code:

```
function onFocusOut() {
    var tester = 0;
    setTimeout(function(){menuReset(tester)},1000);
}

function menuReset(tester) {    
    var hoverCheck = function (event) {
        alert("#navBase a has focus"); //is fired, but to late...
        var tester = event.data.varTester;
        var tester = 1;
    };

    jQuery('#navBase').on('mousemove', 'a', { varTester: tester }, hoverCheck);
    jQuery('#navBase').off('mousemove', 'a', { varTester: tester }, hoverCheck);

    alert(tester);   //This keeps firing first, before the alert in hoverCheck

    if(tester == 1){
        alert("tester = 1");
        return;
    }

    else {
        jQuery('#navBase ul').hide();
        jQuery('#navBase').css({'width': ''});
        jQuery('#navBaseAnchor').css({
            'width': '', 'color': '', 
            'font-size': '', 
            'border-bottom-style': '', 
            'border-bottom-width': '', 
            'border-bottom-color': ''});

        tester = 0;
    }
}
```

Now I keep getting the alert that "tester" is 0, before the hoverCheck function is executed (which should set "tester" to 1) and fires the alert within that function.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alert(tester)` is the first line of code that is executing something you notice as a user. The two function calls `jQuery().on()` and `jQuery().off()` are only attaching event handlers. If you want to see a "1" in the alert, you have to quickly move your mouse before `hoverCheck` is executed. But probably you cannot move your hand faster than JavaScript reaching the next line, which is the `alert()` with `tester` equals "0".

Comment: Aha, thanks. Man i've been at this for days now and this is actually a mayor set back...  Do you know another way to check if an element is currently hovered? (momenteraly at the point of dicarting the entire sub-menu-mess)

Comment: Hmmm... i meant discarting of course. I tried anything from mouseenter, to mouseover, mousemove, to mousein. And i know it isn't focus...

Answer (score 1):

I am also fairly new to JS, but should you also be watching out for variable scope errors too?

You have declared `tester` locally in `onFocusOut()` and in `menuReset(tester)`, and then called it as a global var outside?

From [answers.oreilly.com](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2045-distinction-between-local-and-global-variables-javascript/)

> - LOCAL - Are those that are specific to a function and only work on it.
> - GLOBAL - Are those that are not defined within a function and may also serve to functions unless the function has not required that
>     variable.

Comment: I actually called it globally at first, but since it didn't get passed to hoverCheck() i starrted passing it locally too.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind people...
I found a way around it all.
Currently i'm setting a `.focus()` to the anchor involved on `mouseOver`. (and of course `blur()` on `mouseleave`)
Then it's real easy to check the currently focussed element using `document.activeElement`.

So problem solved, altough in a bit different way.

Answer (score -1):

A little bit different approach would be to set a Javascript timeout() to make the submenu disappear after a certain amount of time if a certain condition isn't met.

Check out [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BPqrK/)

Best of luck!

Comment: You may or may not have checked out my initial code above, but that's precisely what i did. Problem was that the condition you mention was supposed to be "hover". Thing is, javascript can't detect if a element is hovered **right now**. After a work-around for the hover-part i still use a timeout.